# iPhone imageview print screen - creating new image from imageview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, imageview, screen-capture

Can I somehow programmatically make a print screen of one ImageView?

Let's say I'm displaying big photos, with different sizes, scaled automatically (AspectFit) to screen size, centered and with black background. I would like to capture the scaled image including the black imageview background to have 320x480 image to work with.

So how to change for example 350x600 image to 320x480 with black border and without any other elements (buttons, labels) overlaying this imageview? On Android I'm just capturing screen buffer but for iPhone I really have no idea how to do it...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(<specify your size here as CGRect>);
[<yourImageView or view you want to convert in image>.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The `viewImage` is output. As you want a black border so you can have a logic like this, add you `imageView` on a UIView with `blackBackroundColor` as black(remember this view's frame should be greater than your imageView's frame with some margin from each side so that you can have your border)..... and now in  `[<yourView>.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` use this method.

Comment: About this border I just meant the black background when image is scaled aspect-fit inside full screen imageview. Either way, when I'm saving the UIImage to file it's white and empty :(

Answer (score 1):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(320, 480), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    yourImageViewToStoreCaptured = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Saving UIImage *yourImageViewToStoreCaptured to disk results in blank white 8 kb file :( I'm capturing self.imageview.layer.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)saveViewToPhotoLibrary:(id)sender 
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenImage,nil,nil,nil);                                         
    //fill cordinat in place of nil if u want only image comes and not button......ok thanks vijay// 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
```